# Earning points for suggested edits: Is it broken or does the Help page require editing?

Tags: feature-request, bug, editing, reputation, help

I've been meaning to ask this for a while as I haven't come across an explanation anywhere. According to this [help page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), when a suggested edit is accepted the user making the edit earns 2 reputation points.

Now, I can't be 100% sure, but I don't recall **ever** earning 2 reputation points whenever I've edited a question. Why is this?

If it's because my reputation is above 1k, then the help page should be amended to clarify what the *up to +1000 total per user* actually means. I imagine most people would interpret **suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)** as meaning the user will earn 2 reputation points for each edit up to a maximum of 1000 points for suggested edits (i.e. you can earn 2 points for up to 500 edits after which you stop earning points for suggested edits).

Now, if I'm right that a person with over 1000 total reputation is no longer eligible for earning reputation points for edits, then **why would this be the case?** Why should someone stop accruing reputation points just because their overall reputation is above some limit?

I think capping the points one can earn based on their total number of edits makes sense, as this encourages users to get into the habit of editing posts when they think they can improve them. But capping this based on a user's total reputation seems to defeat the intent behind the incentive to take the time to improve someone else's post?

Can someone clarify what's going on? Either way, it seems some action is needed, even if it's just to clarify the help page.